# Are there any standard UI / UX / design principles or guidelines for building Ubuntu apps? 

Tags: application-development, design

Are there any standard UI / UX / design principles or guidelines for building Ubuntu apps?

I'm creating my first app and am afraid it will be too "webappish".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Desktop

In general following the [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/3.4/) should be fine.

Depending on your apps you may have a look at this ones, too:

- [Custom Status Menu Design Guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomStatusMenuDesignGuidelines)
- [Notification Development Guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines)

Answer (score 5):

## Mobile

There are now :)

All Ubuntu apps designed to run on mobile devices should follow the [App Design Guides](http://design.ubuntu.com/apps)