# Ubuntu keyboard shortcut guidelines?

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-development, community

Is there an authoritative specification of keyboard shortcut guidelines for Ubuntu?

I am looking for something like the [OS X guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html) that result in unified application behaviour for common things like accessing the app's preferences, closing an app window, quitting the whole app etc.

If something like this does not exist, where would be the best place to create it and recommend it to application developers in a similar way to e.g. the [Ubuntu design guidelines](https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/design/)? What community body (community council? BDFL?) would have to approve such a document in order to be able to file bugs against applications that do not respect these guidelines?

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/179282/37165) asked on "Are there Human Interface Design Guidelines for Unity Development?" sounds relevant, but it doesn't seem to mention keyboard shortcut at all.